# Can an odd number of marbles jump to infinity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Loosely inspired by the game [Abalone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abalone_(board_game)), I've encountered the following simple problem I cannot solve.
Suppose that we are given a finite set of marbles on an infinite chessboard.
One move consists of one marble jumping over another to an empty space.
For example, if (0,0) and (1,0) have marbles, but (2,0) doesn't, then we can move (0,0) to (2,0).
It is easy to see that there are starting configurations of an even number of marbles that we can "march off" to infinity using such moves.
But is this possible to do with an odd number of marbles?
It feels like this should have a simple explanation, but I don't see any right now.

More on motivation: In Abalone it is useful to start by moving to the center of the board. If one doesn't make sideways moves, then the triangular Abalone board reduces to a chess board. Or almost, because in Abalone it is also allowed to move adjacent marbles in any direction, not just in the direction of the row they are contained in. If one allows that too, then there are more configurations that can do an infinite march. Also, in Abalone one can move at most 3 marbles, so to move as fast as possible, one would always move 3 marbles, and not 2 at a time, but whatever argument works for parity, probably also works for divisibility with 3.

Comment: It's easy to do with 3 marbles if diagonal jumps are allowed, so I presume they're not?

Comment: I assume that each square of the chessboard can accommodate at most one marble?

Comment: Yes and yes - sorry, I haven't noticed these before.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With $5$ you can using the following moves:

```
.....  .....  .....  .....  .....  .....  .....  ..oo.  ...oo 
.....  ..o..  ..o..  ..o..  ..oo.  ...oo  ..ooo  ..ooo  ..ooo 
.oo..  .oo..  .oo..  ..oo.  ..oo.  ..oo.  ..oo.  .....  ..... 
ooo..  oo...  .oo..  ..oo.  ..o..  ..o..  .....  .....  .....
```

So the only numbers of pieces for which no configuration can go to infinity are $1$ and $3$.

Comment: That's a nice example! To be fair to myself, I had an extra condition that the allowed jumps are only upwards and to the right (see motivation), but when posing the question, I didn't include this.

Comment: I see, I included a new sequence which only has those moves (although it is a bit more complicated)

Comment: Wow! beautiful.

Comment: Could you sketch an argument that shows that configurations of larger size can behave the same way? And might there also be disjoint configurations that unavoidably interfere with one another?

Comment: Actually I just thought of this counterexample and that it implies that given $n\geq4$ there is a set of $n$ marbles which can go to infinity. The second question seems interesting even if you only allow moves up/to the right

Comment: Is there a tacit condition that the set of marbles is supposed to retain the same "shape" as it goes to infinity? Otherwise, if going off to infinity is the only condition, then to any finite configuration, we can just add 2 marbles somewhere that march off to infinity independently of what the other marbles are doing.

Comment: I assumed that with "jumping to infinity" he meant that all the marbles eventually leave any bounded set

Comment: Amazing! Interesting that the period is this long. I assume that the next natural question would be to find a set of marbles not divisible by 3 that can go to infinity, if we are allowed to move 3 marbles at a time. Would some simple modification of your construction work?

Comment: By 'moving 3 marbles at a time' I mean that a marble is allowed to jump over exactly two other marbles that are next to it in the same row/column.

Comment: One can also ask whether the group of marbles can reach any location in the infinite chess board (and more precisely, which translations are achievable from the initial position). In your solution, you have translation by $(2,2)$. If I'm correct it's easy to adpat your idea to get translations by $(\pm 2, \pm 2)$ (independent signs) but I don't know if e.g. $(1,0)$ is possible.

Comment: $(1,0)$ is not possible, by a parity argument: the sum of the $x$-coordinates over all marbles keeps the same parity, and there is an odd number of marbles. So the question left is whether $(2,0)$ is achievable.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault true, and $(0,2)$ is achievable if we do not restrict to up/right moves (see the answer before the edit). So $(2,0)$ can be obtained too conjugating by a transformation of 

```
...
.oo
ooo
```

 into 

```
.o.
.oo
.oo
```

Comment: @domotorp it seems there is an analogous construction using $10$ pieces, a marble attached to a $3\times3$ square of marbles (instead of a $2\times 2$ one as in the answer)

Comment: Makes perfect sense, in fact, I see that we can similarly attach two marbles to a 3 by 3 square, so mod 3 doesn't matter. I suppose the last thing to prove is that less than $q^2$ marbles are not enough if one is allowed to move $q$ at a time.

Comment: the only number... is 3... or 1